# How to modify vmlinuz without recompile

Tags: linux, embedded

As title, I have two vmlinuz files on hang for embedded system.

And, I don't have the source and compiler for it, the developer of this embedded system also not work anymore.

The first vmlinuz supports 4 serial comport and two VGA.

The second vmlinuz support 6 serial comport and one VGA.

I want to have a vmlinuz that support 6 serial comport and two VGA.

Does it exist any way to copy the driver from second vmlinuz to first vmlinuz and replace the original one inside the first vmlinuz?

Comment: VMlinuz is a kerbel - it hooks into drivers. Thevsource is available to everyonevas it us the Linux source code - the difficulty may be in recreating a version with only what is needed compiled in. That said, can you provide a directory listing of /boot - its possible there will be a file describing what is built into the kernel (although less likely then on a pc) - if you can get this info you can recompile a new kernel.

Comment: Yes, the OS is using Yocto project(poky). So, I can look into it and try to write a new serial driver for my device?

Answer (score 2):

> Does it exist any way to copy the driver from second vmlinuz to first vmlinuz and replace the original one inside the first vmlinuz?

Short of extensive reverse engineering and binary patching, no.

> I want to have a `vmlinuz` that support 6 serial comport and two VGA.

This is very likely impossible to achieve without the sources.

Even if you have the sources, the fact that they have offered two kernels with different abilities (i.e: tradeoff between Serial vs VGA) implies that there may be a hardware limitation (FPGA / CPLD resources?).

We can't do more than speculate without knowing what the device is.

---

If the device manufacturer has released sources for the BSP (e.g: Yocto), then you may be able to look into it from there - but you'll still probably need to compile *something*.

---

If the device is supported by a mainline kernel (i.e: all sources are in the [kernel.org repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/?h=v5.2-rc1)), then you may have some ability to recreate the configuration and rebuild.

1. Boot the system and run `uname -r` - this is the kernel release

   - For example `4.15.0-48-generic` points toward the [v4.15](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tag/?h=v4.15) release
2. Look for a file named `/proc/config.gz` - on an embedded or more recent system this may not exist

   - This can be decompressed using `gzip -d < /proc/config.gz > ~/config` and subsequently used while configuring the kernel
   - This is only available when the kernel is configured accordingly

     - Distributions have been disabling it more and more for "*security concerns*"
     - On an embedded system it may be disabled to reduce the kernel image size.

Other places to look for the kernel configuration include `/boot` and in a relevant package (if you're using a distribution).

---

If one or both of these don't yield results, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: The existence of config.gz depends not on version, but on the CONFIG_IKCONFIG option, some distributions (and especially embedded devs) just disable it to save space.

Comment: I've added words to clarify... my "_more recently_" comment - which was referencing the trend to remove it for "_security_" rather than a fundamental change in recent releases.